# Web scraping by Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, list, beautifulsoup

In my previous post, I wanna scrape some horse racing data on HKJC. Thanks to the help of Dmitriy Fialkovskiy, I've made it happen by slightly modifying the given code. However, when I was trying to understand the logic behind, there was a line couldn't be explained:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import requests  
import pandas as pd  

url_list = ['http://www.hkjc.com/english/racing/horse.asp?HorseNo=S217','http://www.hkjc.com/english/racing/horse.asp?HorseNo=A093','http://www.hkjc.com/english/racing/horse.asp?HorseNo=V344','http://www.hkjc.com/english/racing/horse.asp?HorseNo=V077', 'http://www.hkjc.com/english/racing/horse.asp?HorseNo=P361', 'http://www.hkjc.com/english/racing/horse.asp?HorseNo=T103']


res=[] #placing res outside of loop
for link in url_list:
    r = requests.get(link)
    r.encoding = 'utf-8'

    html_content = r.text
    soup = BS(html_content, 'lxml')


    table = soup.find('table', class_='bigborder')
    if not table:
        continue

    trs = table.find_all('tr')

    if not trs:
        continue #if trs are not found, then starting next iteration with other link


    headers = trs[0]
    headers_list=[]
    for td in headers.find_all('td'):
        headers_list.append(td.text)
    headers_list+=['Season']
    headers_list.insert(19,'pseudocol1')
    headers_list.insert(20,'pseudocol2')
    headers_list.insert(21,'pseudocol3')

    row = []
    season = ''
    for tr in trs[1:]:
        if 'Season' in tr.text:
            season = tr.text

        else:
            tds = tr.find_all('td')
            for td in tds:
                row.append(td.text.strip('\n').strip('\r').strip('\t').strip('"').strip())
            row.append(season.strip())
            res.append(row)
            row=[]

res = [i for i in res if i[0]!=''] #outside of loop

df=pd.DataFrame(res, columns=headers_list) #outside of loop
del df['pseudocol1'],df['pseudocol2'],df['pseudocol3'] 
del df['VideoReplay']
```

I'm wondering what's the purpose of adding a repeated `row =[]` in the `else` condition and why would that works. Thank you.

Comment: As a fun exercise, replace `row = []` with `row.clear()` and observe the magic.

Comment: res became :[[ ],[ ],[ ],...]  What does that mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `row=[]` inside the loop clears the list, making it empty again. Since the list is declared once before the `for` loop, it would otherwise carry on elements that were appended in one `for` iteration to the other. Doing `row=[]` clears it to an empty list again.

Comment: It should be added that you are assigning it to a new empty list not just clearing it. you could clear it by `del row[:]` but then your res will be affected.

Comment: Do you mean that without the row = [] the result will be res = [['A'], ['A', 'B'], ['A', 'B', 'C'] rather than [['A', 'B', 'C']]?

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, if you do not reset the `row` then you will always repeat the storage of the previous results, more and more, with `res.append(row)` just above.